# camera is zoomed in for a close up render but render is zoomed out

Tags: rendering

Zoom Issues,[image]Hello, I am a noob when it comes to blender, so I apologize up front for not being able to communicate the problem better.  I am following blender guru tutorial on how to model a donut with icing and I have the camera zoomed in for a close up of the donut but when I hit render it is in a zoomed out position, the donut is far away.

My clipping distance is .001 so I don't think it's a clipping issue.  It's as if no matter where I position or zoom camera to, the render is operating on it's own and positioning the camera and focal length farther from my object. I've tried with both EEvee and Cycles but still have the same results. I've also tried different focal lengths, 35mm 50mm and 175mm but still resulting in a zoomed out render instead of a close up shot.

Comment: Is your camera set to orthographic mode by accident?

Comment: No, I started with the camera locked to view so it was easy to move camera around in viewport, it is in perspective

Answer (score 2):

If you zoom out while watching the camera, you'll see a box where everything outside is slightly darker. Inside this box you're seeing what the camera is actually seeing, so simply adjust the camera position to frame the shot you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the issue is but I'll throw in an unlikely but possible issue. Do you  have 2 cameras in the scene? If you do you need to activate the one that's zoomed in by selecting it and pressing ctrl+numpad 0

Comment: No, I just have one camera...I think my problem may be simply bad luck Lol!

Comment: Can you send the .blend file? I'm really curious

Comment: Yes I would like to but I don't know how to do that...I didn't see a way to edit my question so would I have to re-ask the question and attach the blend. file instead of the screenshots?  Please advise I would love to figure out what the problem is

Comment: or you can just upload it to google drive and reply here

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for solution.

[image: solution]

Comment: Please detail the steps in text. Text in images are not searchable, and are not as useful.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Has Timaroberts requested please write the text down in the answer so it can be easily indexed and searched or and can be edited if changes occur. A short explanation of the process would also help

Comment: Thank you! The "Lock Camera to View" (now called just "Camera to View") checkbox was indeed the culprit for me! Blender Guru also mentions it in his tutorial. I guess i was already zoomed in before checking it on the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and kinda got a solution. Just keep zooming into your model and then make a new render, repeat till you get what you want. You might have to zoom until your model covers your entire screen. The zoom you do in your camera corresponds to the zoom in your render, but the ratio is just not 1:1 for some reason.